# Override styled-components with stylesheet

Tags: reactjs, styled-components

Is it possible to override styling that's generated from styled-components with an external loaded stylesheet by html?

Comment: yes you can.. increase the specificity. If you use CSS hash plugin, then you have write CSS generic selector and target the element

Comment: @Nirus Could you explain more in depth?